# Hard Wired Aux In not working

Tags: audio

I just recently purchased a Galaxy Three with 4.0.4. Before the new phone, I had an Apple iPhone 4S. When I plugged the iPhone's headset jack directly to my car receiver's Aux In it worked just fine. When I do the same with the Galaxy, it does not work. I plug one end of the standard 3.5mm male to male adapter cable into the phone it reacts as if a headset was connected - headset icon appears. The Galaxy reacts as if the cable is not present the moment I connect it to the receiver. The headset icon disappears and sound comes from the phone's speakers.

I do not have a bluetooth enabled car so that is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to this - plugging in the iPhone's headset into the Galaxy III? Please clarify - that's the impression I am getting.

Comment: @t0mm13b I believe he's referring to plugging a male-to-male aux cable from his GS3 into the car's speaker system but the S3 is still playing the music out of the phones speakers. The iPhone bit is just to say that it worked for that, why not the S3.

Comment: I understand now, hmmm... male-to-male aux cable not the right kind for GS3? From what I do know, iPhone's headset connectors have it in the reverse unlike ordinary - by ordinary I mean, non-apple headsets... just saying...